How to use deep link for a flutter app when using fcm for a push notification?
I see that there are some other similar questions but this one is different because fcm recently migrated to http v1.
Anyway what I'm trying to do send a push notification in PHP using fcm. When that fcm push notification is clicked it should redirect them through the app to the settings page. My app is a flutter app.
I have already tested the app and made sure the deep linking works.
My results are that it sends the push notification but it isn't deep linked. I have tried using Firebase docs and couldn't find anything for the deeplink. Mine would look something like "click_action":"https://iwingo.site/mobile". The example uses "click_action":"news_intent".
Here is my PHP code:
<?php
// requires variables:
// $notifTitle
// $notifBody
// $notifKey
// $notifRecieverToken
// $deepLink

$notifTitle = "Don't see any rides on IWingo? Follow These Steps In Order To Start Driving!";
$notifBody = "We have a lot of drivers in seattle trying to drive with IWingo. The problem is that we don't have enough riders. Next time you drive for other companies tell your riders about IWingo. Tell them that by cutting out the middle man of these big rideshare companies we create a big gap that allows riders to get a cheaper ride, while letting drivers earn more!";
$notifKey = "HIDDEN";
$notifRecieverToken = "fH1C4c......AD0mB";
$deepLink = "https://iwingo.site/mobile";

if($notifKey == "HIDDEN"){
// This function is needed, because php doesn't have support for base64UrlEncoded strings
function base64UrlEncode($text)
{
    return str_replace(
        ['+', '/', '='],
        ['-', '_', ''],
        base64_encode($text)
    );
}

// Read service account details
$authConfigString = file_get_contents("HIDDEN....56rgu37.json");

// Parse service account details
$authConfig = json_decode($authConfigString);

// Read private key from service account details
$secret = openssl_get_privatekey($authConfig->private_key);

// Create the token header
$header = json_encode([
    'typ' => 'JWT',
    'alg' => 'RS256'
]);

// Get seconds since 1 January 1970
$time = time();

// Allow 1 minute time deviation between client en server (not sure if this is necessary)
$start = $time - 60;
$end = $start + 3600;

// Create payload
$payload = json_encode([
    "iss" => $authConfig->client_email,
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging",
    "aud" => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "exp" => $end,
    "iat" => $start
]);

// Encode Header
$base64UrlHeader = base64UrlEncode($header);

// Encode Payload
$base64UrlPayload = base64UrlEncode($payload);

// Create Signature Hash
$result = openssl_sign($base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $signature, $secret, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

// Encode Signature to Base64Url String
$base64UrlSignature = base64UrlEncode($signature);

// Create JWT
$jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

//-----Request token, with an http post request------
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion='.$jwt,
    'header'  => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$responseText = file_get_contents("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", false, $context);

$response = json_decode($responseText);
$accessToken = $response->access_token;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$apiurl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/HIDDEN/messages:send';   //replace "your-project-id" with...your project ID

 $headers = [
         'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
 ];

 $notification_tray = [
         'title'             => $notifTitle,
         'body'              => $notifBody,
     ];

 $in_app_module = [
        "click_action" => $deepLink
     ];
 //The $in_app_module array above can be empty - I use this to send variables in to my app when it is opened, so the user sees a popup module with the message additional to the generic task tray notification.

  $message = [
        'message' => [
             'notification'     => $notification_tray,
             'data'             => $in_app_module,
             'token'=>$notifRecieverToken,
         ],
  ];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  if ($result === FALSE) {
      //Failed
      die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }

  curl_close($ch);
}
?>

After using that I would get a push notification to the phone but it wouldn't deeplink into the app.
Here is my Flutter App Code:
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

// TODO: Define the background message handler
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
  }
}

// [Android-only] This "Headless Task" is run when the Android app is terminated with `enableHeadless: true`
// Be sure to annotate your callback function to avoid issues in release mode on Flutter >= 3.3.0
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void backgroundFetchHeadlessTask(HeadlessTask task) async {
  String taskId = task.taskId;
  bool isTimeout = task.timeout;
  if (isTimeout) {
    // This task has exceeded its allowed running-time.
    // You must stop what you're doing and immediately .finish(taskId)
    print("[BackgroundFetch] Headless task timed-out: $taskId");
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    return;
  }
  print('[BackgroundFetch] Headless event received.');
  // Do your work here...
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // TODO: Request permission
  final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Permission granted: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }
  // TODO: Register with FCM

  const vapidKey = "HIDDEN";

  // use the registration token to send messages to users from your trusted server environment
  String? token;

  if (DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform == DefaultFirebaseOptions.web) {
    token = await messaging.getToken(
      vapidKey: vapidKey,
    );
  } else {
    token = await messaging.getToken();
  }

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Registration Token=$token');
  }
  // TODO: Set up foreground message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Handling a foreground message: ${message.messageId}');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }

    _messageStreamController.sink.add(message);
  });



  // TODO: Set up background message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  // subscribe to a topic.
  // const topic = 'app_promotion';
  // await messaging.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router, debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,));
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String? action = prefs.getString('session');
  if(action != null && token != null) {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // set value
    await prefs.setString('pushNotifToken', token);
  } else {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // set value
    await prefs.setString('pushNotifToken', token ?? "00");
  }
  // Register to receive BackgroundFetch events after app is terminated.
  // Requires {stopOnTerminate: false, enableHeadless: true}
  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask);
}

.....


final List<GoRoute> dynamicRoutes = announceID.map((id) {
    return GoRoute(
        path: 'announcement/:id',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
          return MaterialPage(
            child: OpenAnnouncementPage(
              shouldOpenAnnouncement: true,
              id: int.parse(id!),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
}).toList();

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Main(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'mobile',
          builder: (_, __) => SettingsPage(),
        ),
        ...dynamicRoutes,
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

If you could help out that would be really nice. I have been stuck for a week!!!
